# Stepping from Point out on Archimedes Spiral for Length along Arc

Tags: algorithm

I wasn’t sure whether to put this question in mathematics or programming?

My question has two parts with the second part dependent on the first.
I’m looking to use Archimedes spirals in some game code I’m writing.

I figured that there is possibly a unary Archimedes spiral from which all other achimedes spirals can be derived.  (Hopefully the use of ‘unary’ is correct here?)  That is a unary Archimedes spiral is one where the spiral spirals one radian outwards for every radian of angle starting at centre.

1. So my first question is:  Is that true?  Can every Archimedes spiral be derived from a ‘unary Archimedes spiral’  like I’ve described?

By derived I mean by the use of simple multiplication and division to transform from the unary Archimedes spiral to any Achimedes spiral with a different rate of out-spiral.

eg.  spiral20RadiansOutPerRadian = unaryspiral * 20

If that is the case then could someone possibly help me also with this second question?

I’m looking to step a measured arc length outwards (and inwards) from a point that is out on a measured Archimedes spiral.  So not from the zero or centre point but from somewhere out on the spiral.  The begin point out on the spiral is represented by a measured radius from zero (or centre).

I’m looking to find:  r' = f(r , arclen)

where r is the initial radius, arclen is the length stepping outwards along the arc (negative to step inwards) and the resultant r' is the new radius at that stepped to point.

My process for deriving from the unit spiral would hopefully then be:

```
Programmer sets a value for delta_radius which is per radian of angle.
Programmer sets a value for start_radius.
Programmer sets a value for step_length which is the length to step around arc.

The unary_step_length is worked out by dividing step_length by delta_radius.
The unary_start_radius is worked out by dividing start_radius by delta_radius.

We call achimedes() function with the two unary values and it returns unary_end_radius.

The actual end_radius is worked out by multiplying unary_end_radius by delta_radius.
The delta_angle is worked by subtracting unary_end_radius from the unary_start_radius.
```

2. My second question is:  Could somebody please help me to write this achimedes() function (if the answer to question 1 is yes)?

I’m looking to have function be of the form:

```
unary_end_radius = archimedes(unary_start_radius , unary_step_length)
```

where the unary_delta_radius is understood to be 1 radian.

Comment: We have some existing Q&A on Archimedean spirals [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/16745/39518) and [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/165103/39518) which may give you some leads.

Answer (score 1):

> Can any Archemedean spiral be derived from one common template?

Yes: you can verify this using the parametric equation itself. Let's define the \$pitch\$ of a spiral to be the rate at which its radius changes as its angle changes. So your "unary" spiral is the spiral with \$pitch = 1\$:

$$Spiral_1(\theta) = 1 \cdot \theta \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta \\ \sin \theta\end{bmatrix}$$

And a spiral with any arbitrary pitch can be expressed as...

$$\begin{align}
Spiral_{pitch}(\theta) 
&= pitch \cdot \theta \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta \\ \sin \theta\end{bmatrix} \\
&= pitch \cdot Spiral_1(\theta)
\end{align}$$

> How can we compute a point a particular length further along the spiral from a given start point?

First we can differentiate our spiral function to get its rate of change:

$$\begin{align}
\frac {d Spiral_{pitch}} {d \theta}(\theta)
&= {pitch} \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta \\ \sin \theta\end{bmatrix}
+ {pitch} \cdot \theta \begin{bmatrix} -\sin \theta \\ \cos \theta\end{bmatrix}\\
&= {pitch} \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta -\theta \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta + \theta \cos \theta\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

And get its length:

$$\left| \left| \frac {d Spiral_{pitch}} {d \theta}(\theta)\right| \right|
=\sqrt{{pitch}^2 \left( 
\left( \cos^2 \theta - 2 \theta \cos \theta \sin \theta + \theta^2 \sin^2 \theta \right ) 
+ \left( \sin^2 \theta + 2 \theta \cos \theta \sin \theta + \theta^2 \cos^2 \theta \right)
\right)} \\
= {pitch} \cdot \sqrt{\theta^2 + 1}
$$

Then integrate this from our starting angle to our ending angle ([using Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sqrt%281%20%2B%20x%5E2%29dx)):

$$
\begin{align}
L &= {pitch} \int_\alpha^\beta \sqrt{\theta^2 + 1}d\theta\\
&= \frac {pitch} 2 \left( \theta \sqrt{\theta^2 + 1} + \ln\left(\sqrt{\theta^2 + 1} + \theta\right) \right) \Biggr| ^ \beta _\alpha
\end{align}$$

Now inverting this beast is a mess, so in the past I've approximated it and then used the Newton-Raphson method a few times to reduce the error to within my needed precision. It's a strictly increasing function whose slope changes very gradually, so it's quite well-behaved for this use, thankfully.

```
// Compute the arc length from the origin to a given angle 
// along a spiral with pitch = 1. radical = sqrt(angle*angle + 1)
float UnitSpiralArcLength(float angle, float radical) {
    return 0.5f *(angle * radical + Mathf.Log(angle + radical));
}

// Given a starting angle, compute a new angle that is a particular
// arc length away, along a spiral with a chosen pitch.
float ShiftSpiralAngle(float pitch, float startAngle, float signedLengthShift) {
    // This square root is both the length of the derivative at this angle,
    // and useful in computing the arc length up to that point, so let's cache it.
    float radical = Mathf.Sqrt(startAngle * startAngle + 1f);

    // On a pitch = 1 spiral, how far from 0 do we start?
    float startLength = UnitSpiralArcLength(startAngle, radical);

    // How far from zero do we want to end?
    float targetLength = startLength + signedLengthShift / pitch;

    // Start with a naive estimate of what angle gets us to here.
    // We use derivative at start angle to guess how much angle to add.
    float estimatedAngle = startAngle + (targetLength - startLength) / radical;

    // Refine our estimate using the Newton-Raphson method.
    // You can adjust a fixed iteration count, or use an error threshold.    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        radical = Mathf.Sqrt(estimatedAngle * estimatedAngle + 1f);
        float error = UnitSpiralArcLength(estimatedAngle, radical) - targetLength;
        estimatedAngle -= error / radical; 
    }

    return estimatedAngle;
}
```

Here I've found it clearer to use angle as my parameter rather than radius, but of course you can convert between them by multiplying/dividing by your pitch.